# Eclipse doesn't see include files when checking syntax but does when building or running the application

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, include

I started with building my project with CMake by using the `cmake <folder> -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` command (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04). Say the results were written to `/home/TestApp` folder.

The thing is that I have header files needed for he application in `/home/some_repo/include` folder. This is also described in `CMakeLists` so after I import my project from `/home/TestApp` to Eclipse as existing code as makefile project, it can successfully be built and runs just as expected.

But in the code edit area there are tons of red underlining which makes it clear that Eclipse can't see the include folder I mentioned before. I tried going to `Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and symbols` and adding that include folder to all configurations and languages but it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

CMake creates an Eclipse project for you. Therefore you need to use: `Import->General->Existing Project into Workspace`.

Comment: I did it. The project works, but still the same underlining. Is there any data I can provide for more information?

Comment: Maybe your are missing `include_directories` in your CMakeLists.txt. Can you provide the file?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/nADor
There are 4 CMakeLists files in several subdirectories. I am new to CMake and actually using these files that were not made by me. Hope you can find any valuable information about the problem here.

Comment: So I finally fixed the problem. But what actually helped was updating my Eclipse platform to a newer one (I installed Eclipse Neon).